# Maintaining a selected object in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, reference

I wanted to know the best approach to store the reference to an object selected, for more clarity:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    int a;
    A(int b)
    {
        a=b;
    }
};
class B{
    public:
    int b;
    B(int a)
    {
        b=a;
    }
};
int main() {
    A a(1);
    B b(2);
    **<<some type>>** x= &a;
    //cout<<x.a or x->a<<endl;
    x = &b;
    //cout<<x.b or x->b;
    return 0;
}
```

**Use case**:
Actually, I am parsing some formatted strings and returning parsed objects(of classes, A, B in return). While parsing the string I get to know what object to fill and what field to fill, to hold this information(changing at runtime) I am looking for a solution. This basically saves me a switch case, and the application is latency-sensitive.

Comment: There is none. It's impossible. C++ does not have this ability.

Comment: @user253751 it has 2 [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: @AlanBirtles But then you still can't do x.b or x->b, you still have to do std::get<B>(x).b which requires you to know the type is B.

Comment: "This basically saves me a switch case, and the application is latency-sensitive" that is a faculty premise (that reducing one switch case is the goal). Because the type is known at runtime you will always have a price to pay, be it a switch case, a vtable indirection (virtual classes) or code size increase (overloads) and a hidden branch (`std::variant`).

Comment: @bolov absolutely, I do understand that hence am looking to get the lowest cost possible, any suggestions?

Comment: Do the simplest thing that works first and *then* start worrying about the cost of a single comparison/switch/vtable indirection. Odds are the rest of your program has much more expensive (time-wise) code that will dwarf this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The described use case sounds to me like an Abstract Factory pattern. You parse something, and then return the appropriate type with some set parameters. And the decision of the type will be made at runtime. By Uuing polymorphism, you can create output as you wish.

Standard problem of abstract factory is that the signature of the constructor must be the same.

But with the below shown solution, you can parse whatever, then instantiate the appropriate type and add parameter values as necessary.

Please check:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

If the answer is not appropriate, please inform me and I will delete it.